# R, intercept a csv file to download from a link

Tags: r, csv, download

i have a link that when open automatically starts a download to a csv file, i need to intercept this csv in R and download it without let the possibility to user to choose where to download the file.

csv is generated on demand and i need to get it

Comment: So when the user clicks on your link, R actually opens it and does something special? I'm assuming you control the computer that the user is on? This may be more technically ambitious than you think--and probably not a good idea--if I'm reading you correctly.

Comment: i have a URL, if i open this URL in browser it generates a csv file and give me the possibility to save it.
i need to lunch the link from R and automaticaly download the file, how i can do?

Answer (score 3):

@ntrax, 'download.file' from the 'utils' package will do the trick.

i.e.

```
download.file(url,destfile)
```

for the many options that are available check ?download.file.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `read.table` to import the csv file as a data frame, for example:

```
fpe <- read.table("http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/effort.dat")
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: no, i do an http request to a website that generates a csv file as response, i need to download it automatically